# Qt loads dll objects into separate thread, why?

Tags: c++, qt

I am having some issues with starting a timer-based object from a dll with the event loop. Therefore I made a minimal example and this is my output:

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is MainWindow(0x28fe08), parent's thread is QThread(0x1222aab0), current thread is QThread(0x121421c8)
QObject::startTimer: Timers can only be used with threads started with QThread
MainWindow thread: 0x1222aab0
DllThreadTest thread: 0x121421c8
```

I am using Windows 8 and Qt5.3.2.

So my questions are:

1. Why is the object that I create from the dll inside a different thread than the MainWindow? As you can see in the code, I am not using threads.
2. I can not pass `this` as a parameter when creating the object from my library as you can see in the first error message. See my example below.

I guess that when I solve the thread-issue, I also solve the timer-problem.

Example:

dllthreadtest.h

```
#ifndef DLLTHREADTEST_H
#define DLLTHREADTEST_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QTimer>

#if defined TEST_BUILD_DLLTHREADTEST
    #define TEST_COMMON_DLLSPEC Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
    #define TEST_COMMON_DLLSPEC Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

class TEST_COMMON_DLLSPEC DllThreadTest : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit DllThreadTest(QObject *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:
    void onTimeOut();
private:
    QTimer timer;
};

#endif // DLLTHREADTEST_H
```

dllthreadtest.cpp

```
#include "dllthreadtest.h"
#include <QDebug>

DllThreadTest::DllThreadTest(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    timer.start(1000);
}

void DllThreadTest::onTimeOut()
{
    qDebug()<<"time out";
}
```

DllThreadTest.pro

```
QT       += core    
QT       -= gui

TARGET = DllThreadTest

CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

CONFIG += debug_and_release build_all
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
win32: TARGET = $$join(TARGET,,,d)
}

TEMPLATE = lib

DEFINES += TEST_BUILD_DLLTHREADTEST

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    dllthreadtest.cpp

HEADERS += \
    dllthreadtest.h
```

I am building it and then including the library in a newly created default project that just creates a QMainWindow. There I instantiate a DllThreadTest-object.

DllImportTest.pro

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = DllImportTest
TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += \
$$PWD/libs/

win32{
LIBS += -L$$PWD/libs/ -ldllthreadtest
}

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

maindwindow.cpp (only class of DllImportTest.pro)

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "dllthreadtest.h"
#include <QDebug>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),
            this,SLOT(onButtonClick()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::onButtonClick()
{
    dllThreadTest_=new DllThreadTest;
    qDebug()<<"MainWindow thread:"<<this->thread();
    qDebug()<<"DllThreadTest thread:"<<dllThreadTest_->thread();
}
```

main.cpp (entry point of DllImportTest)

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: You have two `main.cpp` files, it seems. This is rather suspicious.

Comment: It makes no difference if I remove the main.cpp from my dll project.

Comment: *There I instantiate a DllThreadTest-object* - It suspect that it may be a good idea to show this code.

Comment: I added the code at the end of my post.

Comment: Well, that's strange. Could you add two more debug-outputs to your onButtonClick()-method to check the results of a) `QApplication::instance ()->thread ()` and b) `QThread::currentThread ()`.